# System.Drawing For CoreFX

Tags: c#, .net

What image library can I use with CoreFx? 
I want to write windows/linux app for new .NET https://github.com/dotnet/corefx, but there is no System.Drawing? What can I use for it?

Comment: There are no plans to include support for graphics or a gui.  Use Mono instead.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the GTKSharp project:

http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/gtksharp/